# how to preserve multi-byte characters after parse()

Tags: windows, r, parsing, encoding

When I parse R code with non-native characters under Windows, these characters seem to be turned into their Unicode representations, e.g.

```
Encoding('ğ')
# [1] "UTF-8"
parse(text="'ğ'")
# expression('<U+011F>')
parse(text="'ğ'", encoding='UTF-8')
# expression('<U+011F>')
deparse(parse(text="'ğ'")[1])
# [1] "expression(\"<U+011F>\")"
eval(parse(text="'ğ'"))
# [1] "<U+011F>"
```

Since my locale is Simplified Chinese, I can parse code with Chinese characters without such a problem, e.g.

```
parse(text="'你好'")
# expression('你好')
```

My question is, how can I preserve characters like the letter `ğ` in this example? Or at least how can I "reconstruct" the original characters after I `deparse()` the expression?

My session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                                                   
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: what do you mean by preserve? It doesn't seem to me like anything's been lost. How to 'reconstruct' the character would depend on what your output is, right? Is it a plot? a text file? Do you just want to see the character on the screen? As far as I can tell, Windows doesn't have a general UTF-8 locale, so if you want to see the character as it's meant to be, you'd have to switch R to locale that supports it. (anyone, please jump in if I'm wrong about this).

Comment: Thanks! I think the character `ğ` was indeed lost -- it became `<U+011F>` which is a string consisting of 8 characters (at least after `deparse()` or `eval()`); it is not just a matter of printing on screen. Basically I want to see `ğ` after it is parsed, deparsed or evaluated. It seems I have to use `Sys.setlocale()`.

Comment: @Yihui if you're in a UTF-8 locale, I don't think you'll have those problems. If this is a knitr question, it might make sense for knitr to always default to UTF-8, rather than the users current locale.  I have to do this in devtools (but with the C locale) to ensure files sort consistently across platforms/systems.

Comment: @hadley You are right that I do not have such problems under Ubuntu. Under Windows, I can always use UTF-8 for character encoding, but there is no UTF-8 locale to support it.

Comment: @Yihui any explanation for the change in heart? Does the answer not do what you asked? With 83 views, no additional answers or comments, and one vote, someone less familiar with this place might be inclined to think SO is whack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the problem, is that (quoting [R Installation and administration manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Internationalization)): "R supports all the character sets that the underlying OS can handle. These are interpreted according to the current locale". And unfortunately Windows [has no locale supporting UTF-8](http://www.siao2.com/2007/01/03/1392379.aspx).

Now, the good thing is that Rgui [apparently supports UTF-8](https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/R-2-15-branch/src/gnuwin32/CHANGES0) (scroll down to 2.7.0 > Internationalization). The R parser though, works only with the characters supported in the locale. So a solution that worked for me is to temporarily change the R locale with `Sys.setlocale()` just to do the parsing, and later when deparsing use `iconv()` to convert to UTF-8:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Greek_Greece.1253;LC_CTYPE=Greek_Greece.1253;LC_MONETARY=Greek_Greece.1253;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Greek_Greece.1253"
> orig.locale <- Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")
> parse(text="'你好'")
expression('<U+4F60><U+597D>')
> Sys.setlocale(locale="Chinese")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936;LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936;LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936"
> a <- parse(text="'你好'")
> a
expression('你好')
> Sys.setlocale(locale="Turkish")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Turkish_Turkey.1254;LC_CTYPE=Turkish_Turkey.1254;LC_MONETARY=Turkish_Turkey.1254;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Turkish_Turkey.1254"
> b <- parse(text="'ğ'")
> b
expression('ğ')
> Sys.setlocale(locale=orig.locale)
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Greek_Greece.1253;LC_CTYPE=Greek_Greece.1253;LC_MONETARY=Greek_Greece.1253;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Greek_Greece.1253"
> a
[1] expression('ΔγΊΓ')
> b
[1] expression('π')
> ai <- iconv(a, from="CP936", to="UTF-8")
> ai
[1] "你好"
> bi <- iconv(b, from="CP1254", to="UTF-8")
> bi
[1] "ğ"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have never realized that the `locale` argument in `Sys.setlocale()` could work like this. This solved a puzzle of mine for a long time. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'd be glad to see something simpler surface, but here's a start.

```
eval.utags <- function(x) {
    op <- options("useFancyQuotes")
    on.exit(options(useFancyQuotes=op))
    options(useFancyQuotes=FALSE) # so dQuote/sQuote use ascii quotes

    # replace u-tag with u-escape, e.g., <U+12FF> --> \\u12FF
    with.uescapes <- gsub('<U\\+([[:xdigit:]]+)>', '\\\\u\\1', x)

    # find first quote char ('"' or "'"), if any
    # pick appropriate quote fun, dQuote or sQuote
    first.quote <- regmatches(with.uescapes, regexpr("\'|\"", with.uescapes))
    quote.fun <- if (identical(first.quote, "'")) dQuote else sQuote

    # parse/eval quoted characters 
    eval(parse(text=quote.fun(with.uescapes))) 
}
x <- '<U+011f><U+4f60><U+597d>abc'
y <- eval.utags(x)
y
# [1] "ğ你好abc"
Encoding(y)
# "UTF-8"
```

#### EDIT:

If your original string may have literal unicode tag substrings that you want to preserve as is, before passing it to `parse`, `gsub` all instances of `"<U+"` with the equivalent unicode tags, `"<U+003c><U+0055><U+002b>"`.

```
x <- "'Щ<U+1234>'"
y <- eval(parse(text=gsub('<U\\+', '<U+003c><U+0055><U+002b>', x)))
# [1] "<U+0429><U+003c><U+0055><U+002b>1234>"
z <- eval.utags(y)
# [1] "Щ<U+1234>"
```

This, of course, isn't full proof, though.

It's really a shame this has to be so hackish.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what if I have a literal character string `'<U+011f>'` in the source code? I think this treats the symptom but not the disease. If this problem can be solved by setting a proper locale, I would very much like to accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Yihui Before passing the original text to `parse`, replace all instances of `"<"` with it's unicode tag, `"<U+003c>"`.

Comment: @Yihui as far as setting the proper locale, if there's particular language set you want to `eval/parse`, I'm sure you can find a locale for it on Windows (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318693.aspx). But as far as I can tell, Windows does not have one that supports everything.

Comment: What is worse is that I cannot set an arbitrary locale, e.g. I cannot `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936")` in an R session with `LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252`; R will warn that `OS reports request to set locale to "...." cannot be honored`. It sounds like a Chinese user cannot work with Turkish, and German cannot work with Japanese, etc...

Comment: @Yuhui from `?locales`: "Attempts to change the character set (by Sys.setlocale("LC_TYPE", ), if that implies a different character set) during a session may not work and are likely to lead to some confusion." Did you try setting the locale via the the environment variable, say, in .Renviron? I've updated my Answer once again. Instead of just replacing '<', which is likely to appear outside strings in the source, replace "<U+", which would always be quoted, unless there's some weird situation I'm not thinking of...

Comment: err...replace 'always be quoted' with 'be much more rare than "<" or "<U" to find unquoted'. You could be even more strict and add a look-ahead assertion for four hex digits followed by a '>' immediately after, which altogether would be very unusual to find unquoted.

Comment: The problem with setting the environment variable is that I still can only work with one language. I have got the idea of your `gsub()` solution, so let's stay here at the moment and do not move further down on this track. Thanks!